# Left exactness of Hom

Tags: homological-algebra

For the exact complex $A \to B \to C$, does the complex

$$\text{Hom}(M,A) \to \text{Hom}(M,B) \to \text{Hom}(M,C)$$

fail to be exact?

If not, why do we need the exactness of $0 \to A \to B$ to get the exactness at $\text{Hom}(M,B)$?

Please teach me.

Pierre MATSUMI

Comment: I would suggest you try phrasing your question in a different way.  As it is, I suspect it will be quickly closed.  Anyway, here's a hint, what if $C = 0$?

Comment: This ought to be asked elsewhere, but a hint is that exactness at $A$ imposes an extra condition when it comes to exactness at $B$ (the map from $A$ onto its image in $B$ is an isomorphism).

Answer (score 5):

A functior $\mathcal F$ is called **exact** if the exactness of #
$$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$$
implies exactness of 
$$0\to \mathcal FA\to \mathcal FB\to \mathcal FC\to 0.$$
If we (merely) get 
$$0\to \mathcal FA\to \mathcal FB\to \mathcal FC,$$
the functor is called **left-exact**.

You assume about $\mathcal F=\operatorname{Hom}(M,\cdot)$ that exactness of 
$$A\to B\to C$$
always implies exactness of
$$\mathcal FA\to \mathcal FB\to \mathcal FC.$$
Note that this would imply exactness of $\mathcal F$ as you can apply this to the parts $0\to A\to B$, $A\to B\to C$ and $B\to C\to 0$ and combine.
The Hom-functor really is merely left-exact as can be seen from 
$$0\to 2\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to 0$$
and $M=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$:
$$0\to0\to0\to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to 0$$
is not exact at the right end.
 (Actually, this is the *same* example as given by WillO, only extended to the full sequence).

Answer (score 2):

Try $A={\mathbb Z}$, $B={\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z}$, $C=0$, $M=B$.

Comment: Those A,B,C don't from an exact sequence.

Comment: @Rasmus:  Yes they do.

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: @Rasmus:  How much money you got on you?

Comment: @WillO Um, not exact at A.

Comment: @FranBurstall :  The sequence is of the form $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$.  It makes no sense to ask whether this sequence is "exact at $A$", because exactness refers to both an incoming and an outgoing arrow, and there is no incoming arrow at $A$.  Exactness of this diagram means exactness at $B$, nothing more or less.

Comment: @WillO OK.  Misread the OP's question.  Was misled by slightly non-standard use of "exact sequence".

Comment: @FranBurstall :  On the contrary, if you read the OP's question, you will see that it asks about an exact sequcne of the form $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$ , and then inquires whether we also need a $0$ on the left in order for $Hom$ to preserve exactness.  I gave a counterexample by writing down a sequence of the form specified by the poster, which does not have a zero on the left, and where $Hom$ does not preserve exactness.  That's directly responsive to the OP's question.

Comment: Just to give context to latecomers:  My "On the contrary" comment addressed to Fran Burstall is a response to a comment that he subsequently deleted.  I regret that Fran probably no longer wants to get in on my bet with @Rasmus, but I'm hoping Rasmus still does :)

Comment: Touche. It's exact in the middle. ;)

Comment: (edited to remove -1)